# NodeJS: Array automatically gets converted into object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running into strange problem where a simple array of JavaScript somehow automatically gets converted into object. Here is the code I am using:

```
function readData(callback) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/data/data.xml', function (err, data) {
      parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
          let chapterList = [];

          console.log(typeof chapterList); // strangley this outputs "object"

          for (let i = 0; i <= 113; i++) {
              chapterList.push(result[i].name);
          }

          callback();
      });
  });
}

module.exports = { chapters };
```

As can be seen, on first line I define `chapterList` and on second line it tells me it is type of `object`.

FYI, this is nodejs script which I run like `node index.js`

Comment: In JavaScript you don't have the `Array` type, all classes are instances of `object`.

Those are the only data types:

Primitives:

 - Boolean
 - Null
 - Undefined.
 - Number
 - String
 - Symbol 

And there is also **Object**, so all other variables, if they are not primitves, they are objects. (functions are also objects)

Comment: @Cristy: Thanks I had forgotten this. Clear now thanks